# PostgreSQL Fifo Inventory Calculation

Tags: database, postgresql, fifo

I need to produce following and having hard time connecting the dots. I understand that I need to use CTE but just not able to.

| id | Quantity | Unit Cost | Created at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | 4 | `now()+'1 hour'` |
| 2 | 200 | 5 | `now()+'2 hours'` |
| 3 | -250 | 0 | `now()+'3 hours'` |
| 4 | 50 | 5 | `now()+'4 hours'` |
| 5 | -55 | 0 | `now()+'5 hours'` |

Table/DDL:

```
`CREATE TABLE inventory (
id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY, 
created_at TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE DEFAULT now(),
quantity NUMERIC,
unit_cost NUMERIC(19,2)
);

INSERT INTO inventory (id, quantity, unit_cost, created_at)
VALUES 
(1, 100,4, now()+'1 hour'),
(2, 200,5, now()+'2 hours'), 
(3, -250,0, now()+'3 hours'), 
(4, 10,3, now()+'4 hours'),
(5, -55,0, now()+'5 hours');`
```

Query should produce following:

| id | Quantity | FIFO Cost | Created at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | 4 | `now()+'1 hour'` |
| 2 | 200 | 5 | `now()+'2 hours'` |
| 3 | 100 | -4 | `now()+'3 hours'` |
| 3 | 150 | -5 | `now()+'3 hours'` |
| 4 | 10 | 3 | `now()+'4 hours'` |
| 5 | 50 | -5 | `now()+'5 hours'` |
| 5 | 5 | -3 | `now()+'5 hours'` |

Basically, on negative quantities (invoice, etc) it should use units from positive quantity (purchase, etc) and use up to unused quantity and then go to the next one.

Thanks !

Comment: then why row no 3 exists ? it uses all quantities from row 1 and 40 of row 2 , so it should only be one row with quantity of 150 , fifo 5 or quantity 0 with fifo 4  and 150 fifo 5

Comment: @eshirvana thank you, there was a typo, will correct

Comment: still my point is valid

Comment: According to our story, fifo is calculated from first "IN" entry that hasn't been "used", and then next "IN" until entirety of "OUT" is completed. Therefore, quantity 100, fifo 4 from row 1 and q:150 fifo cost 5 from row 2